# I removed myself from sudo group while installing xampp after following instructions

Tags: grub2, permissions, sudo, recovery-mode, user-management

I removed my self from sudo group in Ubuntu 16.04,

```
 MyUsername is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

& I can't access the recovery from grub because I removed those choices using Grub Custmizer before.
Now, I can't use it again to re-add it because I can't use sudo. 
Any help!?
I have some important files & projects here.

### of course `Visudo` won't work because sudo doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed now. I did as follows

- in grub if you are on dual boot, Selecting Ubuntu & pressing `e` adds kernel parameters so, do that then in Linux, After uuid= , `ro quiet splash` add `single` so it becomes `ro  quiet splash single`. 
  Now it will boot in a mode which allow you to use terminal as sudo.
- If you are on single boot, only ubuntu, hold `left-shift` on bios menu till grub appear, do as above.

**NOTE:** it will write press ctrl + d to continue, this will boot ubuntu as you left it. DO NOT DO THIS. Press Enter, this will choose maintenance mode, Now you can type in the terminal as `sudo` by default.

- type `adduser YOUR_USERNAME admin` if you are on any version under 12.04
- type `adduser YOUR_USERNAME sudo` if you are on Ubuntu 12.04 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch to TTY by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1
Apply following commands:
1. logout
2. 'Login as root'
3. Enter your root password 
4. Edit the sudoer file with visudo 
5. Logout
6. Login as your user
7. Try out if can apply sudo command

Comment: I posted what I did in my answer beneath yours.